# How to open jupyter notebook?

Tags: installation

how can I open the notebook of anaconda python in windows 11?

I couldn't find the app that I downloaded
I am beginner in programming and I am learning paython
I wanted to open the jupyter notebook
I opened cmd and wrote some symbols but it didn't work

Comment: Open the Anaconda Navigator and then choose Jupyter Notebook or JupyterLab from the application icon tiles inside the navigator. There's a ['Getting started with Navigator' page](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/navigator/getting-started/).